# Ограничить поиск по организациям городом?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как ограничить поиск с провайдером yandex#search если для данного поиска не работает опция strictBounds?

Допустим ищем в городе организацию которой точно нет, тогда поиск ищет все равно но где то в другом городе, как этого избежать?

```
    function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
       //координаты нужного города
        center: [53.757547, 87.136044],
        zoom: 12,
        controls: []
    });

    // Создадим экземпляр элемента управления «поиск по карте»
    // с установленной опцией провайдера данных для поиска по организациям.
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search',
            boundedBy: myMap.getBounds(),
            //strictBounds: true, данная опция не работает с этим провайдером

        }
    });

    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

    // Программно выполним поиск организации заведомо отсутствующей в данном городе
    searchControl.search('МКБ');
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Comment: Да, хотелось бы, что бы они и в свой поиск Яндекс.Такси добавили. Возможно, что никак нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, никак. Возможно, имеет смысл взглянуть на API Поиска по организациям: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/

> Для поиска по организациям (`provider: 'yandex#search'`) не работают
>   следующие опции: «noPlacemark», «noCentering», «noSelect»,
>   «**strictBounds**», «kind»

(https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#control.SearchControl__param-parameters.options.provider )

> `boundedBy` - Опция, ограничивающая поиск по карте указанной областью...
>   Доступно только при использовании провайдера `yandex#map`

(https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/searchControl-docpage/ )

Однако использование `boundedBy` может быть полезно:

> При ранжировании объекты, находящиеся внутри указанной области, будут
>   получать больший приоритет

(https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#control.SearchControl__param-parameters.options.boundedBy )

Comment: Это я все читал, поэтому и спрашиваю, может все же есть какой нибудь вариант, ограничить поиск заданной областью, может костыльный способ)

Comment: У меня получилось ограничить запрос к API Поиска по организациям по вашему примеру вот так: https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?apikey=ключ&text=МКБ&lang=ru_RU&type=biz&ll=53.757547,87.136044&spn=0.55,0.40&rspn=1

Comment: Что то не могу сообразить как его прикрутить)

Comment: `ymaps.ready()
   .done(function (ym) {
   var myMap = new ym.Map('bank-map', {
        center: [53.757547, 87.136044],
        zoom: 12,
        controls: []
    }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

jQuery.getJSON('https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?apikey=api-real-key&text=ВТБ&lang=ru_RU&type=biz&ll=53.757547,87.136044&spn=0.55,0.40&rspn=1', function (json) {
    var geoObjects = ym.geoQuery(json)
            .addToMap(myMap)
            .applyBoundsToMap(myMap, {
                checkZoomRange: true
            });
});
});`

Comment: так не работает что то(

Comment: не могу понять почему постоянно ошибка...? `{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Invalid key"}`

Comment: Для API Поиска по организациям нужен отдельный ключ - может, дело в этом? И активируется он, если не ошибаюсь, не сразу, а через 15 минут после получения.

Comment: Да сделал отдельный ключ, уже пара часов прошла, в ЛК написано ключ активирован

Comment: У меня ключ заработал минут через 15. Вот еще что нашел: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/doc/examples/geosearch_examples-docpage/ , последний параграф. Но это не про "Invalid key".

Comment: А как проверили что заработал?

Comment: Сделал вышеприведенный GET-запрос для координат Новокузнецка и для Москвы. В первом случае ничего не нашлось, во втором (https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?apikey=ключ&text=%D0%9C%D0%9A%D0%91&lang=ru_RU&type=biz&ll=37.618920,55.756994&spn=0.55,0.40&rspn=1 ) - нашлось.

Comment: Как то странно работает поиск.... в последнем запросе это координаты не москвы ll=37.618920,55.756994 это голестан какой то. Если ввести координаты москвы то даже по запросу по которому что то должно быть не ищет в москве например вот по этому запросу https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?apikey=ключь&text=ВТБ&lang=ru_RU&type=biz&ll=55.753215,37.622504&spn=0.55,0.40&rspn=1 вот такой ответ http://joxi.ru/krDR19jiJ5opM2

Comment: Я руководствовался документацией: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/doc/concepts/request-docpage/ : параметр ll - это центр области поиска, определяется с помощью долготы и широты, разделенных запятой. Согласно Википедии, координаты Москвы 55°45′21″ с. ш. 37°37′04″ в. д. Обратите внимание на порядок записи координат в запросе.